# Fgets() requires enter to be hit twice after reading to char array

Tags: c

When I enter anything *that evaluates to be false* in function `isFloat(char array[])` I need to hit enter twice to keep the program running.

If I comment out everything but the `fget()` command *everything* requires me to hit enter twice. What could be causing this? I'm flushing `stdin` properly and the `\n` is removed by `strtok()`. Is the `printf()` function causing problems? I've read that `scanf()` and `fgets()` can cause problems when used together. But here they arent.

**Problem Area**

```
printf("first number: ");
    fgets(input, TEN_THOUSAND, stdin);
    strtok(input, "\n");
    success = isFloat(input);
    if(success)
        firstNum = atof(input);
```

**Full Code**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int isFloat(char array[])
{

int m = 0;
int periodCount = 0;

for(m=0; array[m] != '\000'; m++)
    {
        if(array[m] == '1' || array[m] == '2' || array[m] == '3' || array[m] == '4' || array[m] == '5' || array[m] == '6' || array[m] == '7' || array[m] == '8' || array[m] == '9' || array[m] == '0')
            {
            }
        else
            {
                if(array[m] == '.' && periodCount == 0 && m != 0 && m+1 != '\n')
                    periodCount = 1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
    }
return 1;
}

void eatLine()
{
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}

int main()
{

double firstNum = 0.0;
double secondNum = 0.0;
double totalNum = 0.0;
int success = 0;
int TEN_THOUSAND = 10000;
char input[TEN_THOUSAND];

//Outputs assignment header
printf("CS201 - Lab 2 - Number Adder\n\n");

printf("first number: ");
fgets(input, TEN_THOUSAND, stdin);
strtok(input, "\n");
success = isFloat(input);
if(success)
    firstNum = atof(input);

while(!success)
{
    eatLine();
    //The one is for testing purposes
    printf("-- bad input --\n");
    printf("first number: ");
    fgets(input, TEN_THOUSAND, stdin);
    strtok(input, "\n");
    success = isFloat(input);
    if(success)
        firstNum = atof(input);
}

printf("second number: ");
fgets(input, TEN_THOUSAND, stdin);
strtok(input, "\n");
success = isFloat(input);
if(success)
    secondNum = atof(input);

while(!success)
{
    eatLine();
    //The one is for testing purposes
    printf("-- bad input --\n");
    printf("second number: ");
    fgets(input, TEN_THOUSAND, stdin);
    strtok(input, "\n");
    success = isFloat(input);
    if(success)
        secondNum = atof(input);
}

//adds the numbers
totalNum = firstNum + secondNum;

//Solves ugly formatting problem by firstly including a newline 
//after the input is garnered. then it outputs firstNum and totalNum 
//in a field of 11 spaces with a newline terminator. This decrements 
//11 to 10 on the secondNum line to compensate for the space that the + takes up.
printf("\n%11.2f\n", firstNum);
printf("%s%10.2f\n", "+", secondNum);
printf("-----------\n");
printf("%11.2f\n\n", totalNum);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is `eatLine`. There's nothing to eat, since `fgets` already ate the whole line, including the `\n`. So just remove all of the calls to `eatLine` and it should work. Note that you can use `eatLine` with `scanf`, because `scanf` will leave the newline on the input stream, and so there's always something to eat.

Comment: @user3386109 for some format strings, anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I enter anything that evaluates to be false in function `isFloat(char array[])` I need to hit enter twice to keep the program running.

That's because you have a line of code that expects you to enter a line of text.

```
while(!success)
{
   eatLine(); // Culprit
```

Comment: Brilliant! It worked, thanks. So because getchar() stops at '\n' it's waiting for a '\n' to enter the stream correct?

Comment: @TobiasGreen, you are using `while (getline() != '\n')`, which reads and discards everything up to and including the newline character.